# Passing a clearer description to RSpec `its` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm an RSpec newb, but am really loving how easy it is to write the tests and I'm continually refactoring them to be cleaner as I learn new features of RSpec. So, originally, I had the following:

```
describe Account do
  context "when new" do
    let(:account) { Account.new }
    subject { account }

    it "should have account attributes" do
      subject.account_attributes.should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

I then learned about the `its` method, so I tried to rewrite it as such:

```
describe Account do
  context "when new" do
    let(:account) { Account.new }
    subject { account }

    its(:account_attributes, "should not be nil") do
      should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

This fails due to `its` not accepting 2 arguments, but removing the message works just fine. The issue is that if the test fails, the message under the Failed examples section just says

```
rspec ./spec/models/account_spec.rb:23 # Account when new account_attributes
```

which isn't overly helpful.

**So, is there a way to pass a message to `its`, or better yet, have it output a sane message automatically?**

Comment: Side-question since it goes along with this: What is the best RSpec approach for testing that an Account has_many AccountAttributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define an RSpec custom matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_account_attributes do
  match do |actual|
    actual.account_attributes.should_not be_nil
  end
  failure_message_for_should do
    "expected account_attributes to be present, got nil"
  end
end

describe Account do
  it { should have_account_attributes }
end
```

Comment: Thank @zetetic! This is more along the lines of what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @TopherFangio It seems to me that your original `subject.account_attributes.should_not be_nil` would be easier than having to write a custom matcher for every attribute.

Comment: @Kelvin You are correct, however, I would just expand this to simply accept the parameter of the relationship I want to test making the code `it { should have_many :account_attributes }` or something like that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also write: `its(:account_attributes) { should_not be_nil }`

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/subject/attribute-of-subject

Take note that "its" will be extracted from rspec-core to a gem with the release of rspec 3, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a relatively simple monkey-patch will enable what you seek.

Look at the source of the rspec-core gem version you're using. I'm on 2.10.1. In the file `lib/rspec/core/subject.rb` I see the `its` method defined.

Here's my patched version - I changed the `def` line and the line after that.

**Caution - this is very likely to be version specific!** Copy the method from your version and modify it just like I did. Note that if the rspec-core developers do a major restructuring of the code, the patch may need to be very different.

```
module RSpec
  module Core
    module Subject
      module ExampleGroupMethods
        # accept an optional description to append
        def its(attribute, desc=nil, &block)
          describe(desc ? attribute.inspect + " #{desc}" : attribute) do
            example do
              self.class.class_eval do
                define_method(:subject) do
                  if defined?(@_subject)
                    @_subject
                  else
                    @_subject = Array === attribute ? super()[*attribute] : _nested_attribute(super(), attribute)
                  end
                end
              end
              instance_eval(&block)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That patch can probably be put in your `spec_helper.rb`.

Now the usage:

```
its("foo", "is not nil") do
  should_not be_nil
end
```

Output on failure:

```
rspec ./attrib_example_spec.rb:10 # attr example "foo" is not nil
```

If you omit the second arg, the behavior will be just like the unpatched method.